# Livecode Interactive Ads Android

Tags: android, ads, livecode

I'm working off Livecode v5.5.4 on the Android platform... I've been able to successfully publish apps, however, can not figure out how to install inneractive ads... As LC has partnered with inneractive they provide direction which suggests its as easy as...

```
mobileAdRegister "YOUR-AD-KEY" //I've replaced with my APP ID from inneractive

local tDetails

put "30" into tDetails["refresh"] // The advert refresh interval in seconds
put 25 into tDetails["age"] // The age of the target audience
put "male" into tDetails["gender"] // The expected gender of the target audience 
mobileAdCreate "myAd1", "banner", (0,0), tDetails
```

however, nothing seems to work...  any LC ppl out there with advice??... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no error reported from Mark's suggestion you might want to ensure it's visible with:

```
mobileAddSetVisible "myAd1",true
```

Failing that could you post the result of the mobileAds function and let us know if the adLoaded or adLoadFailed message is being sent to the object that executed mobileAdCreate?

Comment: this worked.... and also received the same advice straight from Livecode support... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value of the result:

```
mobileAdCreate "myAd1","banner",(0,0),tDetails
put the result into rslt
if rslt is not empty then
  beep
  answer error rslt
end if
```

Kind regards,

Mark